# How to know whether you are editing a page or a post?

Tags: block-editor

I have different styles applied to pages (I hide the title for them) and posts (I don't want to hide the title here, but style the date of the post). I want to style them differently, which ist possible on the site itself. But in the editor I don't seem to have the possibility to distinguish between pages and posts.

There is no css-class in an upper element which indicates whether I am editing a page or a post which I could use in my css.

How can i know what I am editing in the editor - a page or a post. It's driving me crazy - there must be a way to know this.

Comment: What editor are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`admin_body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/) hook to add your own CSS classes. For example (if you're using Gutenberg):

```php
function pb_admin_body_class($classes) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if (!$screen->is_block_editor()) {
        return $classes;
    }

    $post_id = isset($_GET['post']) ? intval($_GET['post']) : false;
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    if ($post_type) {
        $classes .= $post_type;
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('admin_body_class', 'pb_admin_body_class');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - awesome. Thank you Phil!

Answer (score 0):

The html code must be prepared for it.
For example different classes for the use of css.

example:

```
<div class="pages">
  <a href="#">title</a>
  <?php whatever the page title code ?>
</div>
<div class="posts">
  <a href="#">title</a>
  <?php whatever the posts title code ?>
</div>
```

then the css is easy:

```
 .pages{display:none;}
```

Comment: That is obvious. But how do you set the class depending on what is displayed in the first place? That is actually the question.

Comment: show the code, then we can look for a way. or editing html, or doing some javascript to change css

Comment: that is possible to achieve with javascript

Comment: The code is just the initial Wordpress setup as you can download it on the website. I want to know how I can add a class in the editor (as you described in your answer) , such that I know whether I am in a post or page

Comment: got it, sorry I only know coding it.